# Prove $x(t)\geq x(0)e^{\int_{0}^{t} y(s) ds}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given conditions on $x(t)$ and $y(t)$

1. $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are both infinitely many times differentiable.
2. $x(t)\geq0$ and $y(t)\geq0$ for all $t\geq0$.
3. $x(t)\geq x(0) + $$\int_{0}^{t} y(s)x(s) ds$

Then I need to prove that     $x(t)\geq x(0)e^{\int_{0}^{t} y(s) ds}$

I am just confused how to start, anyone give me some ideas so that I could understand how to begin?

Comment: Do you get anything useful if you differentiate both sides?

Comment: you mean differentiate the condition 3?

Comment: Then, I get $x'(t)\geq y(t)x(t)$, then I think I can solve this system.. wow

Comment: Then why first and second conditions are important?

Comment: @CJD don't differentiate both sides of an inequality!

Comment: This is just gronwall's inequality. Also, you should remove the differential forms tag.

Comment: @alex-tang It seems like a very natural way to prove an inequality is to show equality at some starting point and then to prove that one side grows faster than the other side.  Do you see what I meant?

Comment: @CJD I agree. It just looks like you led op to a tempting but invalid proof.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\left(\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}y(s)x(s)ds}{\exp\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}y(s)ds\right)}\right)'&=\dfrac{y(t)x(t)-\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}y(s)ds\right)y(t)}{\exp\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}y(s)ds\right)}\\
&\geq\dfrac{x(0)y(t)}{\exp\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}y(s)ds\right)},
\end{align*}
so 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}y(s)x(s)ds}{\exp\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}y(s)ds\right)}&\geq x(0)\int_{0}^{t}\dfrac{y(u)}{\exp\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{u}y(s)ds\right)}du\\
&=x(0)\int_{0}^{t}y(u)\exp\left(-\int_{0}^{u}y(s)ds\right)du\\
&=x(0)\left(-\exp\left(-\int_{0}^{u}y(s)ds\right)\right)\bigg|_{u=0}^{u=t}\\
&=-x(0)\exp\left(-\int_{0}^{t}y(s)ds\right)+x(0),
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{x(t)-x(0)}{\exp\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}y(s)ds\right)}\geq-x(0)\exp\left(-\int_{0}^{t}y(s)ds\right)+x(0),
\end{align*}
and we get 
\begin{align*}
x(t)\geq x(0)\exp\left(\int_{0}^{t}y(s)ds\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: One of those magic proofs that very few can find for themselves.